# How to sort a List of integer arrays of varying size?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I've done some extensive searching for this so if this is a duplicate please slaughter me :D

I have a List of byte arrays (List) where the arrays are of varying length. I need to sort the list by the array lengths in ascending order then by the bytes in the array (please see example).

Example:

I want to go from:

```
{0,1,2}
{0,4}
{0,3,2}
{0,1,3}
{0,2,4,6,1}
{0,1,1}
{0,3,4,5}
```

to:

```
{0,4}
{0,1,1}
{0,1,2}
{0,1,3}
{0,3,2}
{0,3,4,5}
{0,2,4,6,1}
```

It's essentially alphabetical order but with a set of numbers instead of characters (arguably the same thing), any ideas?

Comment: Write a custom comparer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is implement a `IComparer<T>` interface and provide that to the sorting algorithm. In this case the algorithm looks like:

```
public ByteArrayComparer : IComparer<byte[]> {

    public int Compare (byte[] ba, byte[] bb) {
        int n = ba.Length;  //fetch the length of the first array
        int ci = n.CompareTo(bb.Length); //compare to the second
        if(ci != 0) { //if not equal return the compare result
            return ci;
        } else { //else elementwise comparer
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if(ba[i] != bb[i]) { //if not equal element, return compare result
                    return ba[i].CompareTo(bb[i]);
                }
            }
            return 0; //if all equal, return 0
        }
    }

}
```

Next you can use the [`List<T>.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
List<byte[]> data = new List<byte[]>();
//add arrays to data
data.Sort(new ByteArrayComparer());
//data is now sorted
```

The sorting algorithm requires that the comparator is valid, a comparator is valid if it satisfies the three constraints on an ordering relation:

1. *Reflexivity*: if an elements is compared with itself, return `0`;
2. *Anti-symmetric*: If *x* is smaller than *y* (return something less than `0`), then *y* is greater than *x* (something greater than `0`);
3. *Transitive*: if *x* is smaller than *y* and *y* is smaller than *z*, then *x* is smaller than *z*.

If the comparer doesn't satisfy that relation, the sorting algorithm will fail to sort correctly, simply because your order makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use `LINQ`

```
MyList = MyList.OrderBy(arr=>arr.Length).ThenBy(arr =>arr.Sum()).ToList();
```

A working example :

```
   List<int[]> a = new List<int[]>();

   int[] t1 = { 0, 4 };
   int[] t2 = { 0, 1, 2 };
   int[] t3 = { 0, 1, 3 };
   int[] t4 = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 1 };
   int[] t5 = { 0, 1, 1 };
   int[] t6 = { 0, 3, 4, 5 };

   a.Add(t1);
   a.Add(t2);
   a.Add(t3);
   a.Add(t4);
   a.Add(t5);
   a.Add(t6);

   a = a.OrderBy(arr=>arr.Length).ThenBy(arr =>arr.Sum()).ToList();

    foreach (int[] item in a)
    {
        foreach (int item2 in item)
        {
             Console.Write(" "+item2);
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
```

Sample output :

```
0 4
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 3 4 5
0 2 4 6 1
```

And as pointed out this could fail in scenarios like {3 4 5} , {4 5 3}

Comment: I didn't dv, but I think it's still incorrect. I think the OP wants to sort lexicographically. So that `{1,200}` is less than `{3,5}` because the first element is smaller. If not look to the second and so on...

Comment: What's first? {0,3,4,5} or {0,3,5,4} ?